# How can list all incomplete downloading on Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management

Sometimes I have to power off my pc when some package is installing, how can I know how many incomplete downloading in my OS (Debian) after I restart my PC?

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

In distros using `apt`, partially downloaded packages reside in
`/var/cache/apt/archives/partial`. Completed packages reside in its parent directory. From `apt-cache` manpage, under section `Files`

```
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/
    Storage area for state information in transit.
```

Your question uses both the words *download* and *install*, which are different phases of software install. If you were middle of an install you may want to use `debsum` to verify integrity of all files. But remember, not all package provides checksum.